# Wasted Space in VS Code Markdown Preview Pane is ... A Pain

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a *README.md* file in VS Code, and I'm seeing over half the preview pane being left blank.  I don't recall this happening when I used VS Code for the same purpose last summer -- I was getting nice full preview panes.

Bug? Misconfiguration on my part?

Screen shot: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPr8U4FsOsEOYJcHgQiMs3XNpPheAdwKAKUkDmCUdIpiEy5WnKIFq4Y-9LVpyXVlg?key=X0RSa1RoeUNMZDQwM0RSTzFscmNjdzBEbnhwSlhn

Comment: This could be a bug, maybe because of the fairly new [minimap feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap). You might want to search for/create a new issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I felt it was better for a bug queue, but vapor locked on where VS Code issues went.  

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24373

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this known issue regarding zoom level and webviews: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5745

I just submitted a PR with the fix: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/24465 Hopefully this fix will be in insiders builds soon and will make it into the next VSCode 1.12 release